# How to delete char from a char array, using backspace?

Tags: arrays, c, char, embedded, uart

My question is, how to delete a char from char array in C using backspace?

```
    char var;
    char rxbuf[20];
    int rx_buf_pos = 0;

    void UART0_IRQHandler()
    {
        if(UART0->S1 & UART0_S1_RDRF_MASK)
        {
            var=UART0->D;   
            if (!enter){
                if(var!=0xd)
                {           
                    while(!(UART0->S1 & UART0_S1_TDRE_MASK)){} ;    
                    UART0->D = var;
                        
                    if (var != 8){  
                        rx_buf[rx_buf_pos] = var;   // Kompletuj komendę
                        rx_buf_pos++;
                    }
                    else{
                        rx_buf_pos--;
                        rx_buf[rx_buf_pos] = 0;
                    }
                }
                else
                    enter = 1;
                
            }
            NVIC_EnableIRQ(UART0_IRQn);
        }
    }
```

I am trying the code above, and when the inserting character from keyboard,
is different than ASCII code for backspace, it's expanding the array.
But I wanna delete last character when a backspace is pressed.
So im doing

```
else {
                  rx_buf_pos--;
                  rx_buf[rx_buf_pos] =0;
```

But it doesn't work. What should I do?
Normally inserting characters to an array works, but there's a problem with deleting them by
a backspace.

** EDIT
After filling the array with chars, then I'm using a strcmp
if (strcmp(rx_buf,"rcv")==0)
to do something with this later.

Comment: I think the answer is "Not." You remove a value from an array by overwriting each entries value with the value from next higher index. And then you somehow ignore the value in the highest indexed entry.

Comment: `char rxbuf[];` is this legal in your compiler?

Comment: @DavidRanieri No sorry, I was handwriting these global variables, in code I have char rxbuf[20];

Comment: You should check that `rx_buf_pos` is not zero before decrementing it, and you should also check for overflow before incrementing it. Other than that though, it should work.  You could consider using `'\b'` to indicate backspace instead of using `8`.

Comment: Possibly the problem is that your terminal emulator doesn't send 8 when you press backspace.  There are several different options for this.  In any case, don't use magic numbers like 0xd, or 8.  Use named constants or literals.  Eg: change 0xd to '\r' so that anyone looking at the code knows what it is supposed to mean.

Comment: @TomV thanks a lot, that helped! It turned out, that PuTTy considers backspace as a delete -> "127" ascii char. Now it works fine.

Comment: I'd suggest using TeraTerm Pro, but even in PuTTY that behaviour is configurable:  In the PuTTY Configuration dialog, under _Terminal->Keyboard->The Backspace key_.  Since this is an issue with tour terminal configuration and not your code, voting to close.